# Editing and fixing table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is a question that relates to a MySQL database.

Running the Schema module on the site, I was getting the following mismatch re the Internationalization module:

[image]

I was trying to get the "actual " to match the "declared."

If I went to the database with phpMyadmin, and looked at the "group_context" index of the I18N_STRING table, I got the following:

[image]

How could I get the second array *[array('context', 50)]* to display next to the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this as follows:

- Made a dump of the table DATA (without the table structure;)
- Deleted the whole table (structure and data;)
- From a fresh Drupal install, I made a dump of the table structure only (with no data;)
- Imported this new table structure into the database;
- Imported into the new table the data that I had dumped originally.

Now the actual index appears like the declared index.

Hope this helps someone. :)